# Keypress event won't activate with $().load("page.html") jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I can't interact with inputs after I use $(".content").load("Dashboard.html")

Example:
1. Index page containing div(with class "content") loads
2. Use $(".content").load("Dashboard.html") to load a page into that div.
3. $("input").keypress(function(e) { alert("test"); }); won't work.

Code:

```js
// jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {

 $(".content").load("pages/Dashboard.html");
    
 init();
});




function init() {


 $("input").keypress(function(e) {
  alert("1");
 });

 $("input").keydown(function(e) {
  alert("2");
 });


}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="content">Dashboard.html with input will show here</div>
```

Thanks for taking the time to read this!

Comment: You need to call init in the `complete` handler of your `.load()`, otherwise init is called before the new HTML is inserted.

Comment: It seems that you have input in loading file pages/Dashboard.html. so you should bind keypress on parent or document element as input will be loaded dynamically and initially not loaded in dom. Check below code:

    function init() {
    
        $(document).on('keypress', 'input', function(e) {
      alert("1");
     });
    
     $(document).on('keypdown', 'input', function(e) {
      alert("2");
     });
    }

Hope it helps you.

Comment: @RohitMittal Thanks! That works now! But I got a new problem,
output = $("#output")[0];
alert(output);
Will alert ''undefined"

Comment: Please follow above pattern to make that work. Bind all jQuery events like that. for this , you need to bind like $(document).find("#output")[0].

Comment: @RohitMittal Thanks again! I understand now :)

Answer (score 1):

You have no `<input>` tag yet you are calling it with your keypress function. Use `document` instead:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    alert("1");
});
```

working snippet:

```js
// jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".content").load("pages/Dashboard.html");
  init();
});

function init() {
  $(document).keypress(function(e) {
    alert("1");
  });
  $(document).keydown(function(e) {
    alert("2");
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">Dashboard.html with input will show here</div>
```